# Disassemble specific mach-o function

Tags: disassembly, objdump, mach-o, llvm

I have a mach-o binary and using `llvm-objdump` version 9 I can disassemble it.  I would like to disassemble only a single function though.

If I display the symbol table with `--syms` I can see the function I would like to disassemble:

```
0000000100005a54 l     F __TEXT,__text -[ViewController isValidPin:]
```

however I cannot work out the proper command to do this.

I have tried the following options which all just result in the usage being displayed and no indication what the issue is with the command:

- `llvm-objdump-9 --dis-symname "-[ViewController isValidPin:]"`
- `llvm-objdump-9 --macho --dis-symname "-[ViewController isValidPin:]"`
- `llvm-objdump-9 --macho --dis-symname "isValidPin"`
- `llvm-objdump-9 --macho --dis-symname "- isValidPin"`
- `llvm-objdump-9 --macho --dis-symname "- isValidPin:"`
- `llvm-objdump-9 --macho --dis-symname "-isValidPin:"`

If I use `--disassemble-functions` with all of the above variations on the command name it just shows all the disassembly and not just `isValidPin`, including if I add the `--demangle` flag.

If I try and do it using --start address, i.e.:

```
llvm-objdump-9 --macho --start-address=100005a54
```

or `0x100005a54` I get the following error:

```
llvm-objdump-9: for the   --start-address option: '100005a54' value invalid for ulong argument!
```

If I convert that to decimal instead it just shows the usage again. If I add a stop address as well it shows the usage regardless of whether that is in hex or dec.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450076/how-can-i-make-objdump-disassemble-from-a-specified-start-address-on-macos-catal) similar question however it is trying to do this on macOS and also the answer there is just suggesting what I have tried.

The only other mention I can find of `llvm-objdump` on here is me answering another question.

Googling just seems to lead me to different versions of the man page or discussion on commits to the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this on a sample binary using single quotes around the sym name:

`0000d2a0 l     F __TEXT,__text -[MasterViewController managedObjectContext]`

```
$ llvm-objdump-9.0 -m -d --dis-symname '-[MasterViewController managedObjectContext]' MachO-iOS-armv7s-Helloworld 
MachO-iOS-armv7s-Helloworld:
(__TEXT,__text) section
-[MasterViewController managedObjectContext]:
    d2a0:   82 b0   sub sp, #8
    d2a2:   43 f6 2a 12 movw    r2, #14634
    d2a6:   c0 f2 00 02 movt    r2, #0
    d2aa:   7a 44   add r2, pc
    d2ac:   01 90   str r0, [sp, #4]
    d2ae:   00 91   str r1, [sp]
    d2b0:   01 98   ldr r0, [sp, #4]
    d2b2:   11 68   ldr r1, [r2]
    d2b4:   08 44   add r0, r1
    d2b6:   00 68   ldr r0, [r0]
    d2b8:   02 b0   add sp, #8
    d2ba:   70 47   bx  lr
```

Maybe single quotes are the missing piece.

Comment: Thank you Mega Tonnage!  The problem was that I had not included -d.  As the description for --dis-symname is "disassemble just this symbol's instructions (requires -macho)" I wrongfully assumed you wouldn't also have to tell the command to disassemble with -d but that was pretty much the only combination I hadn't tried.  It works with " or ' as long as you include -d.  Thanks again.